# How do you clear a specific JSON object in a JSON array within localStorage by a delete button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a program that simply add's students to a table and stores that information into local-storage. I can add students and see the data stored into local-storage, but my big problem is figuring out how to remove a specific object within local storage upon button click after adding it (without clearing all of local storage).

Link for test: https://www.chriscaldwelldev.com/studentIA/student.html

**Here is the table and inputs (HTML):**

```
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <h1 class="title">Student Manager</h1>

        <div class="controlCenter">
            <table id="studentTable" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Student Number:</th>
                        <th>Name:</th>
                        <th>Address:</th>
                        <th>Phone Number:</th>
                        <th>GPA:</th>
                        <th>Academic Plan:</th>
                        <th>Level:</th>
                        <th>Status:</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="students"></tbody>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" id="studentN"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="name"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="address"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="phoneN"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="gpa"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="ap"></td>
                        <td><select id="selectL" name="SelectL">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select...</option>
                            <option value="freshman">Freshman</option>
                            <option value="sophomore">Sophomore</option>
                            <option value="junior">Junior</option>
                            <option value="senior">Senior</option>
                            <option value="graduate">Graduate</option>
                        </select></td>
                        <td><select id="selectS" name="SelectS">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select...</option>
                            <option value="active">Active</option>
                            <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <input id="add" class="addButton" value="ADD">

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

**Here is the JS:**

```
// when the document loads
            $(function(){

                // add an onclick function to the id=add button 
                $("#add").click(function(){

                    var studentN = $("#studentN").val();
                    var name = $("#name").val();
                    var address = $("#address").val();
                    var phoneN = $("#phoneN").val();
                    var gpa = $("#gpa").val();
                    var ap = $("#ap").val();
                    var selectL = $("#selectL").val();
                    var selectS = $("#selectS").val();

                    if(studentN==null || name==null || address==null || phoneN==null || 
                        gpa==null || ap==null || selectL==null || selectS==null){
                        alert("All Fields Are Required to Add a Student");
                        return;
                    }

                    //create JSON object with text inputs with key:value pairs
                    var student = {
                        studentN: studentN,
                        name: name,
                        address: address,
                        phoneN: phoneN,
                        gpa: gpa,
                        ap: ap,
                        selectL: selectL,
                        selectS: selectS
                    }

                    //load local storage
                    var students = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("students"));

                    //if empty
                    if(!students){
                        students = [];   
                    }

                    students.push(student);

                    localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(students));

                    // store a copy of the row in the body
                    var row = $("<tr>");

                    // store a copy of the current state in the <td> tag  
                    var studentNData = $("<td>");
                    // now change the innerHTML for that <td> 
                    studentNData.html(studentN);
                    // append the new value to our row
                    row.append(studentNData);

                    (...)

                    // store a copy of the current state for the next <td> tag
                    var selectSData = $("<td>");
                    // change the inner html of the <td>
                    selectSData.html(selectS);
                    // append the new value to our row
                    row.append(selectSData);

                    var deleteButton = $("<td>" + "<input type=\"button\" class=\"deleteButton\" value=\"X\">");
                    row.append(deleteButton);

                    // on the DOM, put the new row on the top of the list
                    $("#students").prepend(row);

                    // reset the values of the text inputs to empty strings 
                    $("#studentN").val("");
                    $("#name").val("");
                    $("#address").val("");
                    $("#phoneN").val("");
                    $("#gpa").val("");
                    $("#ap").val("");
                    $("#selectL").val("");
                    $("#selectS").val("");


                });

                var students = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("students"));

                $("#studentTable").on('click', '.deleteButton', function () {
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                    //I can't think of what to do here...

                });

                if (students) {

                    // loop through the entire JSON array stored in local storage
                    for (i in students) {

                        // get a current copy of the content in the row
                        var row = $("<tr>");

                        // store a copy of the current state in the <td> tag, update the innerHTML, then append it to the DOM at the end of the row
                        var studentNData = $("<td>");
                        studentNData.html(students[i].studentN);
                        row.append(studentNData);

                        (...)

                        var selectSData = $("<td>");
                        selectSData.html(students[i].selectS);
                        row.append(selectSData);

                        var deleteButton = $("<td>" + "<input type=\"button\" class=\"deleteButton\" value=\"X\">");
                        row.append(deleteButton);

                        // now add the row to the DOM at the beginning of the list
                        $("#students").prepend(row);
                    }

                }

});
```

I assume that whatever I need to do primarily needs to be done in the deleteButton onclick. I've thought some ideas through but they seem super wrong. I appreciate any help if you can.

Comment: *" I've thought some ideas through but they seem super wrong"* Would you mind sharing those idea's and the reason why you haven't tried them or decided to use them? Thank you.

Comment: @NewToJS Well since students is an array, I thought maybe for a second I could make a hidden input field that would act as an index, so every 'add' would create a key pair of index=0, 1, 2, 3 etc. in an object. I then thought I could maybe increment through the student array until its index equaled the value of index in the object and delete that object. However, this seems impossible to keep up with after several deletes and not good for practice. Ideas like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution you could use is adding a `data-studentn` attribute to your delete buttons. Then, when the delete button is clicked, you can load the students array from localStorage, remove the student with that studentn, and save the new students array.

Change

`"<input type=\"button\" class=\"deleteButton\" value=\"X\">"`

to

`"<input type=\"button\" class=\"deleteButton\" value=\"X\" data-studentn=\"" + students[i].studentN + "\" >"`

Note: Remember to do something similar in the other place where you create a delete button.

Under `//I can't think of what to do here...` you can do the following:

```
var deletedStudentN = $(this).attr('data-studentn');
var students = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("students"));
students = students.filter(function(student) {
    return student.studentN != deletedStudentN;
});
localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(students));
```

Comment: Although this might work I think it would be better to use a `data-` attribute since creating a random one of your own seems invalid. The purpose of `data-` attributes is for custom attributes so I would recommend using valid markup.

Comment: @RockySims Thank you for the response! I will try this and let you know if I got it to work.

Comment: Good update but just so you are aware, `jQuery` have a function for `data-` attributes `.data()`. Here is the [**jQuery .data() documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) It might be of some use when appending the delete button and to target the custom `data-` attribute set upon deleting. It might be worth adding the documentation in your answer if you choose to use `.data()`

Comment: @RockySims, after adding the suggested code, it did not quite work. After doing some console.logs I found that the variables were as expected though. (such as deletedStudentN and students[i].studentN).

Comment: Your solution worked! I read through it again and realized that the `student = students.filter` needed to be `students = students.filter`. I appreciate both of your guys' help @NewToJS and @Rocky Sims!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. I updated my answer to fix the bug you found (just in case anyone else comes along and uses it).